# How to make some elements draggable and other droppable using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I want to drag some elements and drop it in some other containers. The following example works for objects that are both draggable and droppable

http://jsfiddle.net/AwCuM/

But when I try to make some of them draggable and others only droppable it doesn't work

http://jsfiddle.net/4adJk/10/

I know how to use jQueryUI to do this, but I want to do the same using pure HTML5.

Comment: I want to achieve the same functionality as shown in the following demo http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [Mozilla's HTML docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#section_6)
I found that I need to handle the `dragover` event.
The complete solution can be viewed at:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dema8/7/

Comment: your mozilla link is out of date now.

Comment: the fiddle that you supplied is also broken.